Pause and resume a Python script execution in Spyder without debugging (like in Matlab)
Is there a way in Spyder (Spyder 5.5.0) to pause the execution of a Python script (Python 3.12), leave the laptop in sleep mode, and then resume execution later without debugging the code? I want to run a simulation using 'Run file (F5)' Run file (F5) in Spyder in Spyder, pause it during my commute from the office to home, and continue running it when I reopen the laptop at home.
In MATLAB, there's a similar functionality with Run all sections (F5), then Pause the currently executing code and enter debug mode (Ctrl + F5) and then Continue Running (F5), but I'm unsure if it's available in Spyder for Python scripts.
Thank you
I would like to:

Press Run file (F5) in Spyder (Matlab correspondent Run all sections (F5))
Press something to pause the execution of the Python script (Matlab correspondent Pause the currently executing code and enter debug mode (Ctrl + F5))
Press something to continue the execution of the Python script (Matlab correspondent Continue Running (F5))

I have tried to press  Run file (F5) in Spyder and then press Stop debugging (Ctrl+Shift+F12) and then in the IPython Console write In [2]: !continue. This does not work as it tells me 'continue' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I have also tried to press "Ctrl+F5" and then press Stop debugging (Ctrl+Shift+F12) and then in the IPython Console write In [2]: !continue. This does not work as well for the same reason.
